# Per Display fractional scaling in Gnome 3.26

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, scaling

As I am about to move to Ubuntu 17.10 after years of KDE/Plasma, I came to no conclusive answer if Gnome 3.26 will support *per display* fractional scaling.

I am ware of the scale-monitor-framebuffer experimental setting but will it be possible to set monitor 1 to eg. 150% scaling and monitor 2 to 125%  and if so, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It's possible to set this in gnome-control-center.

Screenshots:

- [external 4k-Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9SaP.png)
- [built-in laptop-Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbMA9.png)

both displays are set to 150% but it’s possible to adjust this per display

Comment: Is this on X or the  Wayland experience?

Comment: Only wayland. Non-wayland-apps (Xwalyand) look blurry on scales different than muliples of 100%

Comment: Since this was a top hit for me on google trying to find how to set per display scaling I wanted to add how I got it working. I'm running Pop!_OS 19.10 with Gnome 3.34.2 which uses X11 by default (instead of Wayland).

Display settings was showing only 100% and 200% options and I was unable to set it per display. After following https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/enable-fractional-scaling-ubuntu-19-04 by running `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"` I got more options (125%, 150%, 175%) and surprisingly it also started working per display!